# Namespace class of component not found in script.php during clean install of component

Tags: joomla-4, namespace

in file script.php of component made for Joomla! 4.0-beta2-dev the namespace isn't found : Class 'Kunena\Forum\Libraries\Install\KunenaModelInstall' not foundClass

The changes in script.php : https://github.com/xillibit/Kunena-forum/commit/cad399955edb9368663935e5a22b8d91d2f953e0

The backtrace during installation :

[image]

Why the namespace isn't found in this case ?

P.S. : at the same time when i see the error, i look into \administrator\cache\autoload_psr4.php and i can see the namespace :

```
'Kunena\\Forum\\Libraries\\' => [JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/kunena'],
```

and i found the file at the place where it should be : \libraries\kunena\Install\kunenamodelinstall.php

Thanks by advance

Comment: It looks like (for me at least) that it is still a bug in Joomla 4 that the `JnamespacePsr4Map` class did not auto register newly installed `libraries`' namespaces, thus those 3rd party libraries' namespaces will not be included in `autoload_psr4.php` file. At least that is how I see it at the moment. It should be reported to core Joomla development, I think.

Comment: I do not have a clue how you have seen the library namespace/path in the `autoload_psr4.php` file as it is not written in that file.

Comment: I had seen the file autoload_psr4.php under cache under administrator, we have opened a new issue : https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/29552

Comment: The problem has to be cleared a little more, since if you put the following in `postflight` before calling your `new KunenaModelInstall` object, then your namespace will be registered for a while: `JLoader::registerNamespace("Kunena\Forum\Libraries", JPATH_LIBRARIES . "/kunena", $reset = false, $prepend = false, $type = 'psr4');` and your class/namespace will be there, no problem with that. You will find few other problematic methods then but let's focus on this library namespace registration first...

Comment: I mean, the namespace is going to be available temporarily using the above method, but it still not be in `autoload_psr4.php` file.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention (maybe it is too obvious) that copying the above `JLoader` method into your system plugin (even in the `__construct()` of that Kunena system plugin ), your library namespace is going to be registered always, as that method was standardly used in Joomla 3.x.x for registering libraries' classes/namespaces. That way you can continue your development for J4. I do not believe that core Joomla will apply the feature of auto-registering libraries namespaces for months from now as I see...

Comment: But putting the JLoaded that you has given above in our system plugin, it still fails with the errorshowed in my first message. in postflight by doing that, i don't fail but it doesn't find the component id : `JLoader::registerNamespace("Kunena\Forum\Libraries", JPATH_LIBRARIES . "/kunena", $reset = false, $prepend = false, $type = 'psr4');`

`$installer = new KunenaModelInstall;
$installer->createMenu();`

Comment: Probably you are inserting that `JLoader::registerNamespace()` line into a wrong place in your system plugin. I’ll check this a bit later and give you exaclty where (which line) you should put this, because I have already tried that and worked without a problem. But at the moment I’m not at my laptop...

Comment: I mean there is some problems with your system plugin too, later I’ll write about that too...

Comment: Thanks to have take the time to look at it. We have found a workaround for it : https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/commit/85c63867ac86ee49270bac1c068d652a7aa4d57c

Comment: Ohh, OK, great!